# Dynamically disabling omnibox in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, omnibox

While developing a chrome extension with an omnibox feature for quick search within the data, I need to add support to enable/disable the omnibox feature of the extension from the extension options, but could not find any way to do so.

The workaround I'm doing at the moment is removing the listeners, and setting the default suggestion description to "Search is disabled", but I would like to completely disable the feature, so the keyword will not trigger the omnibox.

Is it even possible?
If so, any idea how?

Comment: No. It's not possible.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you